# SQL - Date format conversion issue (AUTO to 'MM/DD/YYYY')

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I have a column in a created table called "Date1", that has dates formatted as AUTO (ex. 2022-06-17).  I am trying to query that column, but need the date formatted as 'MM/DD/YYYY', yet everything I've tried returns an error of some kind.

When I try `date(Date1, 'MM/DD/YYYY)` the error says that it can't parse 2022-06-17 for MM/DD/YYYY.  When I try `to_date(Date1 [MM/DD/YYYY])` or `try_to_date(Date1 [MM/DD/YYYY])` the error says it doesn't recognize MM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see my answer below ... since your column is already of type DATE, the only way to present it in the format you want is to (1) change the output format for DATE columns at the session level, or (2) use to_varchar(<date_col>, 'MM/DD/YYYY') and present it in a string format.  There is no other DATE formatting option at present with Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to *display* the date using a specific format, you're converting to a varchar rather than a date:

```
select to_varchar(current_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

If you're trying to compare a column with a date to a formatted string in `MM/DD/YYYY` format then:

```
select current_date = try_to_date('08/04/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: to_varchar worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to provide correct format to match `2022-06-17` literal:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE(Date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM tab_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column is already of type DATE.  TO_DATE() and TRY_TO_DATE() convert non-date formats (string, integer) to a DATE type.  They are not a means to format your DATE for presentation.

Date data type and presentation format are indepent.

You can alter your session to change the default display format of a date, but the underlying representation in the database remains the same.

```
alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY';
alter session set DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY';

select <col_name> from table; -- Now will show as MM/DD/YYYY for date columns
```